# C# MongoDB: identify if Insert synchronous operation success

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm working on a **.net mvc app** and I use MongoDB as the database.

I have created this code for inserting data that works on MongoDB:

```
public bool Insert(Log source)
{
    IMongoDatabase db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(DataBase);
    IMongoCollection<Log> collection = db.GetCollection<Log>("log");
    collection.InsertOne(source);

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that `InsertOne` does not return any thing, and I want to control if the data is inserted succesfully.
I see that, if the database is disconnected, after a few seconds of calling the operation returns a `System.TimeoutException`.

I have search in Google and I only find answers for asynchronous operations. So my question is, for doing a good *control of success*, have I to control more Exceptions to have a good control of insertion?

Comment: MongoDB use WriteConcern 1 as default, this means your operation is propagated at least in the Primary database. If you want to have more <consistence> then you can also specify a WriteConcern journal in order to be sure that the data was also 'stored in the journal' (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/). Basically the operation is returned successful if your operation is propagated correctly to the Primary.